# Why MobileFrontend MediaWiki extension doesn't display Main Page?

Tags: mobile, mediawiki

I've installed MediaWiki, enabled short URLs there and added Interwiki and MobileFrontend extensions. But MobileFrontend extension doesn't show the Main Page - the output is just [empty](http://en.wikinames.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile). The real page is [not empty](http://en.wikinames.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop). At the same time MobileFrontend correctly displays other pages (see for example [this page](http://en.wikinames.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Version&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile)).

What could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: There is a HTTP code 500 on the main page (Internal Server Error). Please check the logs (in /var/log/apache/error.log or elsewhere), it will give more information about the error.

Comment: Thanks, @Seb35! The error there says `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding()`. Looks like it is because of missing `mbstring`. But `composer.json` contains ext-mbstring`` in `suggest` section. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Yeah, `suggest` wasn't enough, moved it to `required`, works well now. Could you please your comment as answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Comment: Great you solved the issue. mbstring is a [PHP module](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mbstring.php) and is sometimes installed by default or could be installed with a package.I didn’t know it was possible to install it via Composer, so perhaps an improvement would be to add ext-mbstring in the require section of MobileFrontend.

Comment: I was about to open a bug, but I have only found mb_convert_* functions in MediaWiki (file includes/HtmlFormatter.php) and not in MobileFrontend. In your error log, what file did the error comes from?

Comment: Oh, I don't have the log already (heroku keeps only last 1000 lines of the file). But MobileFrontend doc (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend) says that `mbstring` module is required.

Comment: Yeah, I should have looked at the extension page, so indeed there is already [a bug to remove this dependency](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T62174).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a HTTP code 500 on the main page (Internal Server Error). The server logs are often a good idea to start debugging.